# VueJS : Including some static HTML and JS

Tags: vue.js

I am very new to VueJS coming from a mustache project.  It was very easy to include common bits of HTML (footer, google tracking code etc).

How do I do the same with VueJS, some of the ways I read seem to be complete overkill (writing import components).

I have:

src

- components

  -- App.vue
- assets

static

- footer.htm

Comment: Components are [not an overkill](https://jsfiddle.net/ugsfe2rp/2/). They are the building units you use to manage complexity.

Comment: I may be missing something, just add to `index.html` outside of `<div id="app"></div>`. Use `<script>` for js and `w3-include-html` for html. Using vue cli 3, to include the bits in the build put them in the `public` folder.

Comment: I tried w3-include-html inside the html and didnt seem to work, does VueJS block it

Answer (score 2):

For the html, write components with just a `<template>` section.
Importing and using components inside components is very common in Vue,
I wouldn't call it "complete overkill", you can also inject html into an element using the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive, but I wouldn't recommend that for html you've writen yourself.

For the tracking code, it's a bit trickier as you can't just add `<script>` tags inside the template part of a component or v-html.
I recommend saving the tracking code as `google-tracking.js`, etc and `import './google-tracking.js'` in your app.